# How to remove "tns:" and "xmlns:" from xsl:stylesheet in a JDeveloper SOA XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, soa

I have the following code, created by XSLT Transformation in SOA JDeveloper:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:mhdr="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.mediator.service.common.functions.MediatorExtnFunction"
            xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc"
            xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/dbSelectStores"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20"
            xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions"
            xmlns:socket="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.adapter.socket.ProtocolTranslator"
            xmlns:oracle-xsl-mapper="http://www.oracle.com/xsl/mapper/schemas"
            xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue"
            xmlns:oraxsl="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java"
            xmlns:ns0="http://www.xxxxx.it/BO/transformation/types"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.xxxxx.it/bo/dataexchange"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xsd oracle-xsl-mapper xsi xsl ns1 ns0 tns mhdr oraext xp20 xref socket dvm oraxsl"
            xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype"
            xmlns:plt="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/"
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:jca="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/wsdl/jca/"
            xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/IntegrationBackOffice/BOTransformations/dbSelectStores"
            xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/IntegrationBackOffice/BOTransformations/TransformationBPEL"
            xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/ftp/IntegrationBackOffice/BOTransformations/ftpCEDETLReference"> <xsl:param name="StoresInvoke_OutputVariable.dbSelectStoresOutputCollection"/><xsl:template match="/">
  <tns:VSBODataExchange>
  <tns:Import ImportId="{/ns0:input/ns0:flowId}" ImportDate="{xp20:current-date ( )}">
    <tns:Stores>
      <xsl:for-each select="$StoresInvoke_OutputVariable.dbSelectStoresOutputCollection/ns1:dbSelectStoresOutputCollection/ns1:dbSelectStoresOutput">
        <tns:Store Operation="IU" ItemNo="{position ( )}">
          <tns:StoreId>
            <xsl:value-of select="oraext:right-trim(ns1:BS1000)"/>
          </tns:StoreId>
        </tns:Store>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tns:Stores>
  </tns:Import>
</tns:VSBODataExchange>
</xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VSBODataExchange xmlns:jca="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/wsdl/jca/" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/IntegrationBackOfficeToshiba/BOTransformations/dbSelectStores" xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/ftp/IntegrationBackOfficeToshiba/BOTransformations/ftpCEDETLReference" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:plt="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/IntegrationBackOfficeToshiba/BOTransformations/TransformationBPEL" xmlns:tns="http://www.gabriellispa.it/bo/toshiba/dataexchange" xmlns="http://www.gabriellispa.it/bo/toshiba/dataexchange">
    <tns:Import ImportId="420036" ImportDate="2020-07-07">
        <tns:Stores>
            <tns:Store Operation="IU" ItemNo="1">
                <tns:StoreId>401</tns:StoreId>
            </tns:Store>
        </tns:Stores>
    </tns:Import>
</VSBODataExchange>
```

But my output must be without "tns:" in the element tag and, possibily, without "xmlns:" in the xsl stylesheet, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<VSBODataExchange>
<Import ImportId="5" ImportDate="2018-08-06">
<Stores>
<Store Operation="IU" ItemNo="1">
    <StoreId>1</StoreId>
</Store>
</Stores>
</Import>
```

How can I replace the "tns:" from tag element and remove all the "xmls:... " from the stylesheet in the output?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking too much in terms of the lexical output, rather than the XDM tree of nodes that your stylesheet is generating. You need to think about the expanded name of the elements in the result tree (an expanded name is a namespace URI plus local name), and leave the serialization to look after itself.

You are getting namespace declarations and prefixed names in the output because you are creating elements in a non-null namespace. To fix it, you need to generate no-namespace elements. The first step to achieving that is to get rid of the "tns:" prefix from all the literal result elements in the stylesheet. That may be all you need to do: it's hard to tell.

I guess there's some reason you have 20 (largely) unused namespaces declared in your stylesheet, but it's not good practice. You can't assume they are simply ignored.